# .png as background images on navigation bar

Tags: html, css, nav, divide

I am very new to HTML and CSS and this is not a project, but rather I am discovering things on my own. I am trying to create a navigation bar using lists (`ul`, `li`) and wanted to put a search icon and user log in icon along with the other text on the nav bar. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <div class="navBarIcons">
            <li class="searchIco"><a href="">search</a></li>
            <li class="userIco"><a href="">user</a></li>
        </div>
        <li><a href="">OVERCLOCKING</a></li>
        <li><a href="">PERIPHERALS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">STORAGE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">POWER SUPPLY</a></li>
        <li><a href="">GRAPHIC CARDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">MEMORY</a></li>
        <li><a href="">MOTHERBOARDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">PROCESSOR</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
.userIco {    
    background-image: url(userIco.png);    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    background-size: 25px;    
    background-position: center;    
}

.searchIco {    
    background-image: url(searchIco.png);    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    background-size: 25px;    
    background-position: center;    
}

.nav li a:hover {    
    background-color: #195ca1;         
    color: #f2f2f2;         
}
```

What I would want to do is to hover on the icons and it would still be there (as you can see in the screen cap it disappears when I hover)

[image: Screencap]

if I remove the text it wont be properly aligned and when I hover it doesn't cover the whole block of the background

[image]

Comment: Care to post your :hover css? Although from the screengrab what is likely happening is that you've set `background: color`, which will reset all backgrounds set to only the color. If this is the case, what you want is to re-define only the color, so that nothing else gets altered, like in `background-color: color`

Comment: Divs aren't allowed as children of a `ul`...it's invalid HTML. Equally, `li` can't be children of anything other than a `ul`.

Comment: @Forty I have added the css code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `background-image` is set into the `<li>` element, but your `background-color` is set to your `<a>`, so it is being on an upper layer than the `<li>`. You should set the `background-color` to `li:hover` instead, or perhaps move your `background-image` to the `<a>` element. The image needs to be on the same or higher layer than the background-color.

Comment: This `.nav li:hover {

 background-color: #195ca1;
 color: #f2f2f2;

}` seemed to fix it but the text is still there, and if I remove the text the positioning goes all wrong. This is what I'm talking about: http://oi68.tinypic.com/2m7vpqa.jpg

Comment: How did you try to remove the text? I think you could keep it there (still useful for screen readers) and set it to `font-size: 0` or `color: transparent`. Setting font size to zero or removing the text will remove the space it adds, so you might need to add a width to the a or li, depending on how the rest of your code is set up.

Comment: okay I fixed it, you gave me the idea. I set the `.searchIco a { opacity: 0; }` then it was all fixed. Thank you!